# foreach limit in swiftUI

Tags: arrays, swiftui, text, foreach

What is best way to limit ForEach count? Let me know if anybody knows the best way to limit this.

I tried "arrayItem.prefix(n)" but I found no changes.

ForEach(0..<viewModel.prop.prefix(1), id: \.**self**) { item **in**

Comment: if you are looking to get an `index`, try  this: `ForEach(viewModel.prop.prefix(1).indices, id: \.self) { index in .... }`

Comment: Great...!!! It's working with "viewModel.prop.prefix(1).count" but not with "ForEach(viewModel.prop.prefix(1).indices". Anyway thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: very strange, I would like to understand this and learn from it. Can you show an example where `ForEach(viewModel.prop.prefix(1).indices, id: \.self)` does not work.

Comment: Please check my previous question. For that view i modified my List with ForEach and that's how it worked for me.

Comment: `ForEach` is not a for loop, very common beginner mistake with SwiftUI. With an array that changes `id: \.self` will cause a crash!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into this today and using array slicing on your ForEach works but when using indices you need to place .prefix() after .indices()

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(data.prefix(5), id: \.self) { item in
                Text("\(item)")
            }
        }
        Divider()
        VStack {
            ForEach(data.indices.prefix(5), id: \.self) { index in
                Text("\(data[index])")
            }
        }
    }
}
```